# CASE in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SELECT statement in T-SQL which replace null string to "N/A"

```
select 
  firstName,
  lastName,
  case city
    when null then 'N/A'
    else city
  end,
  case state
    when null then 'N/A'
    else state
  end 
from 
  Person left join Address on Person.personId = Address.personId
```

Output in T-SQL:

```
 ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
 Allen                          Wang                           N/A                            N/A
 Bob                            Alice                          New York City                  New York
```

How do I do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Why not use `COALESCE`? It does the same and is an ANSI function.

Comment: Same, no? You could use coalesce() for an easier approach.

Comment: In T-SQL, `COALESCE` is *literally* a short hand `CASE` expression, @CetinBasoz , so yes, *the same*.

Comment: Though, in T-SQL, those `CASE`'s `WHEN` expressions will never actually evaluate to true. They will *always* return the value of `state`, and never `'N/A'`. Unless you are setting `ANSI_NULLS` to `OFF`; which is strongly recommended against.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're comparing to `NULL`, and standard SQL semantics of comparisons of `NULL` don't work like this. A simple case uses `=` (equals) behaviour, and `something = NULL` is `UNKNOWN`, which inside a `CASE` behaves as `FALSE`.

Solutions:

1. Use `coalesce`:

   ```sql
   coalesce(state, 'N/A'),
   ```
2. Use a searched case instead of a simple case:

   ```sql
   case when state is null then 'N/A' else state end
   ```

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/GHWG38c5

Comment: @CJChang And as Larnu states in the comments above, this - with default settings - also applies to SQL Server, see https://dbfiddle.uk/OIQP8GSb. The behaviour you're basing your question on means that you - IMHO unwisely - turned off ANSI NULL behaviour.